# how to close whole application in android

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to kill an application with all it's activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/android-how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)

I tried with **finish()**.

But it just close the present activity not whole application.
as the another activity is running hide it shows when i finish the above activity..

**CODE :**

```
public class third extends  Activity{

Button btn_back, btn_finish;
Intent intent2;
Bundle b1;


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third);


        intent2 = getIntent();
        b1=intent2.getExtras();
        String spin = b1.getString("name");
        String gender = b1.getString("gender");



        btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_finish = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Toast.makeText(third.this, spin + "" + gender , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent2 = new Intent (third.this,second.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });

        btn_finish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
 }
```

}

Comment: You'll have to set a boolean flag within a class extending application, then within onPause of each activity if this flag is set call finish() for that activity (i.e. this will cascade finish() your whole app);

Comment: Please learn to spend at least 10 minutes researching for yourself before submitting a question, this question has been asked many, many times before

Comment: System.exit(0) is not working...

Comment: When you write a question, SO will show you a list of similar questions asked before. In your case any of those suggestions would have answered your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this line of code:

```
System.exit(1);
```

The `integer` 1 is just a return code.

**EDIT**
This was answered when I first started android development: Please do not use it. You could try [Adding an Exit button to Android Application](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/01/adding-exit-button-to-android.html).

Comment: `System.exit(1)` would be slightly more correct. A result code of 1 is seen as an expected exit by the Android system. Also using `System.exit()` is considered bad practice on Android.

Comment: @silent_killer The Android System is probably restarting your process and restoring the Activity stack since Android is not supposed to work like that.

Comment: I edited it as @mibollma said .. please try it and report

Comment: not @mibollma it is not working as the behind activity was onPause state as it shows when i finish last activity.

Comment: its not Working :(