# How to implement exit button behaviour?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application, i have exit button to exit from the application. So i have `finish()` all the activities. But i loses h/w back button behaviour. So my question is: I want to go back to all activites and also want to exit when clicking on exit button..

Comment: didn't get you problem..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application)

Comment: @ashish please see the question again..i have edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your question is little bit confusing but i think you need this

[Finish all activities when back button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028667/finish-all-activities-when-back-button-is-pressed/10028853#10028853)

and never use system.exit for exiting application [Close application and launch home screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application)

### edited

---

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener()
{
       public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
        startActivity(intent);

       }
});
```

Comment: Nope..I want to back all activites but when clicking on exit it should exit the app..

Comment: will application exit on clicking exit button? as you are recreating intent?

Comment: yes it will take you out from application and also clear your activity stack because in it we have added flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

```
System.exit(1)
```

may help.. arguement is important.. you can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937120/switching-between-activities-in-android/9937281#9937281) approach..

Answer (score 0):

you may want to override `onBackPressed()` method and call `finish()` inside it

Comment: No..it will still come out of application.. i want to move to back page and also want to exit from application when i click on exit button..

Comment: Can you please describe the scenario? I don't get the question either, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code ...I hope it work

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    am.restartPackage(componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

/**easiest way that I found and working. Setting up `onclick="exitBtn"` for button in XML file. and defining that button in java*/

```
public void exitBtn(View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OderActivity.this); // this will pop up a dialog box for OK or Cancel//
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: if u don't want to include the dialog box, then u can remove all the alert dialog codes and simply put from intent to finish() lines from the above code.