# Clearing all activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 4 Activities 1.Home,2.B,3.C and 4.D. Whenever I start Home from Activity D I want to finish all other activities. I Used this code, but when I press back button from Home it brings me to the previous activity. What I did wrong here.?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);        
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: call finish() method every time when you call the class.

Comment: Are you want to close all your activities when pressed back from activity D?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l/9580057#9580057

Comment: Issue is while i press back button from Home..what if add android:nohistroy="true".. Will this finish all activities?

Comment: finish previous activity when starting new activity. check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/10028968/1476699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This will work only for activities which are still in the activity stack. I believe you are finishing the Home Activity when going to B. So that `CLEARTOP` won't work.
Now try something like this.

You need to set an Extra with intent Of "D" to Home. Then you have to check the Intent extra in Home, call `finish()` if the extra matching

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, Home.class);
    intent.putExtra("urString",defaultvalue);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    // Checking the intent extra at "HOME"
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("urString")){
      // manage your own way            
      finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: As described in [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) documentation

> This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to start the root activity of a task, it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the foreground, and then clear it to its root state. This is especially useful, for example, when launching an activity from the notification manager.

Comment: If you are starting the activity from another activity in the same task (which is the usual case), using `FLAG_ACTIVIY_NEW_TASK` is useless.

Answer (score -1):

In manifest.xml file set android:nohistroy="true" for all the activities

Comment: This is a horrible answer. You clearly do not understand how activities work. The `noHistory` flag is there for very exceptional cases.