# What's the right way to take down the entire Activit(ies) stack if one of them suffers a fatal crash?

Tags: android

As a follow up to ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/android-how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)):

I'm curious what if any event is fired when an Activity dies a painful death.  My intention is to not leave any Activity on the stack living and I'm happy to start them all with startActivityForResult() as the answer in the above thread suggests, but I'm concerned that no result is sent back if the activity that's supposed to send back the flag crashes rather than exits organically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

If a child activity fails for any reason (such as crashing), the parent activity will receive a result with the code RESULT_CANCELED.