# How to exit Activity 1 on clicking exit in Activity 2 which is called from Activity 1

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi guys

I wanted to ask : I have a first activity that opens the second activity in the Activity menu. I press exit in Activity 2 and would like you to also close the Activity 1. How to do this?

Comment: See this tutorial http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: please clearly state your problem !! http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html  this explains Starting Another Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start an Activity B from Activity A, use `startActivityForResult(...)`. When you want to close the entire app, you can do something like this:

```
    setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
    finish();
```

You can check **[How to kill an application with all its activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/android-how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)** for detailed description