# Exiting cleanly after a crash on the UI thread

Tags: android, uncaught-exception

I've implemented an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in my Android code.  If an error occurs, it first logs some diagnostic data, then it attempts to exit.  I've followed the recipe in [How to kill an application with all its activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities?lq=1) so that Activities cascade in closing.

This works when the error is in a non-UI thread, or when the main activity is active.  However, if the error occurred on the UI thread on a subordinate Activity, the calling Activity never wakes up.  `onActivityResult()` never gets called, and the application hangs.  Is there any way to exit cleanly after the UI thread crashes?

Here's a simplified version:

```
public void uncaughtException( final Thread t, final Throwable e )
{
    Activity ac = currentActivity();
    ac.setResult( 99 );
    ac.finish();
}
```

in the main activity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class );
    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}

protected void onActivityResult( int rqC, int resultCode, Intent data )
{
    if ( resultCode == 99 )
    {
        setResult( 99 );
        finish();
    }
    super.onActivityResult( rqC, resultCode, data );
}
```

Comment: Could you post some more of your code so that we can see what you are doing?

Comment: Have you tried using finish() when you catch the exception?

Comment: Simplified code added via edit to post.

Comment: as the activity have crashed, i am not sure if you still can trigger that finish-sequence, if i where you, i would add a broadcast receiver in each activity, and then send a finish command from `uncaughtException()` so all activities will call `finish()` inside thier `onReceive()` , maybe without `setResult(99)` as all activities will close and no need for `onActivityResult()` to be triggered, I AM not sure if this is correct to do, or even if it will work, i will just give it a try