# android-activity start from where it closed when I exit the app

Tags: android

in the MainActivity , I have this code for closing the application :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        super.onBackPressed();
    }else {
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
    }
```

I should press 2 back button when I want to close the application .

The problem is ,when I close the application, it starts from another activity , mostly from the last activity I've been to .

How can I always start the activity from mainActivity not other activities ?

Comment: Know the onResume method? You will have to fiddle around that!

Comment: just don't call super.onBackPressed at the end

Comment: You are navigating to Home when you are exiting from your application. Is this you want to do.

Comment: And yes one more thing if you are on other activity then how you are moving to main activity for running the above code??? Are you finishing all  activities???

Answer (score 2):

***Use these lines of code..***

```
    @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
  if (exit){
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
        finish();
      }else {
         exit = true;
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
           public void run() {
              exit = false;
          }
       }, 3 * 1000);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to kill all the activities when you are closing your application, have a look at this [How to kill an application with all its activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)

Answer (score 1):

override the onBackPressed method of your MainActivity as shown below

```
private int backpressedCount;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    backpressedCount++;
    if (backpressedCount == 2) {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this part of code in every / in which activity is starting automatically,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
YourActivityName.this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the launchMode: singleTask or singleInstance

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```