# Closing App from inner Activity

Tags: android

I have two different activities. The first launches the second one. I want to close the app from second Activity but using finish() the first activity is automatically displayed instead of closing application .How can I avoid this?

Comment: when you start second activity from first activity at that time call finish

Comment: thanks buddy it worked perfectly :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3106670/3702862

Answer (score 0):

As @user3676184 mentioned, you can finish first activity ones you launch second activity. i.e.

Implement this in first activity from where you are launched your second activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); //this will finish ActivityOne and only ActivityTwo will be present and when you call finish in ActivityTwo it will close.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to close the app from second Activity but using finish() the
>   first activity is automatically displayed instead of closing
>   application .How can I avoid this?

Because `FirstActivity` is added in back-stack and pop-up back when pressing back button on `SecondActivity`.

To get required behavior, after starting `SecondActivity` call `finish()` method in `FirstActivity` to remove from stack :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
FirstActivity.this.finish(); //<< close FirstActivity here
```

Answer (score 0):

when you start second activity from first activity then call method finish()
like,

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```