# How to kill tasks in android?

Tags: android

I use the following snippet to kill tasks , it works perfectly fine but it doesn't kill my own app. How do i make it kill my app as well?

```
// kill tasks
    List<String> reservedPackages = new ArrayList<String>();
    reservedPackages.add("system");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.launcher2");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.inputmethod.latin");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.phone");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.wallpaper");
    reservedPackages.add("com.google.process.gapps");
    reservedPackages.add("android.process.acore");
    reservedPackages.add("android.process.media");
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> listeProcessus = am
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo processus : listeProcessus) {
        String packageName = processus.processName.split(":")[0];
        if (!context.getPackageName().equals(packageName)
                && !reservedPackages.contains(packageName)) {
            am.restartPackage(packageName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you go through this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently removed the GET_TASKS permission and developers can't make changes to running tasks . The only remained way is to have a root access and close the running tasks that is not possible for All Android Users

Comment: on what Api level? and how can you support your arguement? where is the documentation?

Comment: BTW i'm not using that permission and your didn't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

As of api 21 (android lolipop) it has been removed by Google

Comment: you need to take a break.