# how can i close an application using "onBackButtonpressed" from any activity in my android application

Tags: android

I need to close my application when the user presses the back button from an activity that is **not** the main activity(i.e the launcher activity). The answers I've seen so far actually works on the main activity of the application(i.e the launcher activity)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10597017/2435238

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill an application with all its activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    <YourActivity>.this.finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the back stack while you open the activity using flag :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

And your appliction will be finished when you go back.

Or may be Try to open same activity but clear the back stack and finish it at same time.(not tested)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourCurrentActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```