# Killing foreground service on Android

Tags: android, android-service, foreground

I'm working on Android 12 and I try to (force) kill my foreground service.

I can kill it from adb by the command:
adb shell force-stop "my service"

But when I do it programmatically (as was suggested by [How to kill an application with all its activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)) the OS restarts the service after it was killed.

That's my code which kill the service but then is initialized by the Android OS:

```
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(0);
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: To stop your service, call `stopService()`.

Answer (score 0):

While the kill is an abnormal termination and the OS restarts the service, the following code is a clean exit from the application similar to force-stop:

finishAffinity();
System.exit(0);

Comment: `finishAffinity()` is only relevant for activities. It does nothing to services. Calling `System.exit()` is basically intentionally crashing your OS process. This is not the same as force-stop, because if you force-stop an app, it will never run again until the user manually starts it.

Answer (score 0):

Android is restarting your `Service` because of whatever the `Service` returned from `onStartCommand()`. This value tells Android what to do if the `Service` is killed. You've probably returned `START_STICKY` which will cause Android to restart the `Service` if it is killed (for whatever reason) while started. If you don't want that to happen, return `START_NOT_STICKY` or some other value that won't cause Android to restart your `Service`. Also, as @CommonsWare suggested, you can just call `stopService()` to stop your `Service`. Killing the OS process is a very harsh (and not recommended) way to stop a running `Service`.